# Why Java compiler Not get the duplicate class error while defining an inner class inside a loop

Tags: java, runtime, javac, compile-time

As you know we can define an inner class inside a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    class InnerClass {
        void aMethod() {
            System.out.println("Inner Class Method");
        }
    }
}
```

But Why the compiler does not give us error like **`Duplicate class: 'InnerClass'`** because the same name of repeated class?

I imagine that above code is equivalent to:

```
class Inner {
    void aMethod() {
        System.out.println("Inner Class Method");
    }
}

class Inner {
    void aMethod() {
        System.out.println("Inner Class Method");
    }
}
```

Comment: Because ever iteration wipe out previous scope

Comment: The java compiler does not execute the loop - it only compiles it (and it creates the .class file for the `Inner` class exactly once). The execution of the loop happens at runtime - but at runtime there is no class creation. At runtime you create instances of classes.

Comment: @muasif80 No, because the compiler doesn't execute the loop.

Comment: Oh my bad I misunderstood the question. Yes at compile time there is no reason why would it give duplicate error, even you can define a variable it does not give error that its duplicate. But the idea is same as I understand each iteration is a different iteration than the previous one. This does not make sense why it should complain about duplicate declaration. And its just the loop body definition. At execution time when the loop body will be entered only then these variables will get created and will be available only in loop block.

Answer (score -1):

There are two things to keep in mind here:

- First of all, as Thomas Kläger said, the compiler does not execute the loop, so he can't know the class is "repeated".
- But most important, is the fact that the class is inner to the loop scope, so at the end of each iteration, the class is virtually "destroyed" and redefined at the begining.

Comment: The class is never destroyed at all, nor redefined either. It is defined at compile time.

Comment: But virtually it does, because at runtime, the class can only be called on the loop scope and after the class definition.